# retrieving the value of the combox to another combobox.,

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, combobox

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

I have two Combobox.

```
-Combobox1.Text
-Combobox2.Text
```

first combobox1 contains the ff: items

```
-Globe
-Smart
-Sun
```

Second combobox2 contains the ff items:

```
-Smart30
-Smart60
-Smart115
-AMAX
-Globe30
-TU20
-TU50
-TU150
-DCTU100
```

What I want to do is when I click for Globe in ComboBox1.Text -AMAX and -Globe 30 Appears in the second ComboBox2., and for Smart when I clicked it., -Smart30,-Smart60 and -Smart115 appears in ComboBox2.,just like in SUN.,

So is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have to store *these* data into a `Dictionary<string,List<string>` and use data-binding technique to assign `List<T>` to comboBox2 of selected `Key` of `ComboBox1`.

Sample:

```
 Dim data As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))
 data.Add("Select", New List(Of String))
 data.Add("First", New List(Of String) From {"A", "B", "C"})
 data.Add("Second", New List(Of String) From {"P", "Q"})

 ComboBox1.DataSource = data.Keys.ToList()
 AddHandler ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged, 
      Sub(sa, ea)
          ComboBox2.DataSource = data(ComboBox1.Text)
      End Sub
```